# Simple algorithm for finding maximum and minimum of given values

Tags: algorithm

No code is needed, only simple math theory.

Like:

- print "enter your age"
- read(age)
- if age>20
- result="adult"
- print"you are"
- print(result)

I am going to attend C language classes but before that I want to learn some basics.
I need a program/algo that finds maximum and minimum of three numbers using **multiple-if or nested-if**.

Comment: imagine you throw three dice, how would you find the max and min values using you two hands and two eyes ? If you can do it then you can write an algorithm :)

Comment: I don't know what the pseudo code has to do with the question title, but it's useful to note that `min(a,b,c) = min(min(a,b),c)`, so you really only need a `min()` function/macro that handles two items (`max()` is similar). That would get ugly for a longer list, but for only three items, that's probably the simplest approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the straightforward way:

```
int min(int a, int b, int c){
    if (a <= b && a <= c){
        return a;
    }
    if (b <= a && b <= c){
        return b;
    }
    if (c <= a && c <= b){
        return c;
    }
}
```

There's the way with the minimum number of comparisons:

```
int min(int a, int b, int c){
    if (a < b){
        if (a < c){
            return a;
        }
        else{
            return c;
        }
    }
    else{
        if (b < c){
            return b
        }
        else{
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

There's the way with the fewest lines of code, thanks to the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#C):

```
int min(int a, int b, int c){
    return (a<b)?((a<c)?a:c):((b<c)?b:c);
}
```

There's the way twalberg mentioned in the comments:

```
int min(int a, int b){
    if (a <= b){return a;}
    else{return b;}
}

int min(int a, int b, int c){
    return min(min(a,b), c);
}
```

max can be defined in all of these ways too, replacing `<` with `>`. You can also define it in terms of `min`:

```
int max(int a, int b, int c){
    return -min(-a, -b, -c);
}
```

If you don't wish to learn how to declare functions yet, you can drop some of these straight into your main function. For example, the second method:

```
//todo: translate this pseudocode into C
print "enter three numbers"
read(a)
read(b)
read(c)
if (a < b){
    if (a < c){
        min = a;
    }
    else{
        min = c;
    }
}
else{
    if (b < c){
        min = b
    }
    else{
        min = c;
    }
}
print "the minimum value is " + min
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the problem requirements there are two implications that will determine the best solution of the problem:

1. You will have to check every number to get the solution
2. The best solution implies check every number just once

It would be something like that:

```
1: Maximum = 0
2: Minimum = 0
3: read(number)
4: if number > Maximum then Maximum = number
5: if number < Minimum then Minimum = number
6: Repeat from 3 as many times as needed
7: Print Maximum and Minimum
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: This is not C; it's Javascript.  However, for such a general problem, the lessons are the same - and, in fact, because of the syntactical similarities, much of the same code can be used in an equivalent C performance test.

In [this JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/minmax-linear-recursive-native), I have four methods of getting the min/max of an array of numbers.  The first does it the straightforward way:

1. Set min and max to arr[0]
2. Start loop at 1, using index i

   1. Check if arr[i] < min; if so, set min to arr[i]
   2. Check if arr[i] > max; if so, set max to arr[i]
3. At end of loop, respond with an array containing [ min, max ]

The second uses a divide and conquer approach.  This is normally an improvement over O(n^2) problems (e.g., a sort, in which every value has to be compared to every other value using the straightforward implementation), but for O(n) problems like this, doesn't gain you anything, and adds stack overhead.

4. If the array is 1 element long, return [ arr[0], arr[0] ]
5. If the array is 2 elements long

   1. If arr[0] > arr[1], return [ arr[1], arr[0] ]
   2. Otherwise, return arr
6. Split the array roughly into a left half and right half, calling minmax on each half
7. return [ min(left[0], right[0]), max(left[1], right[1] ]

There's another version of the recursive that uses indices to avoid creation of new arrays to perform the split (Array#slice() creates a new array from data in the old array; allocations of this sort can bog things down).

Then there's the native solution using JS's Math library, as a reference point.

I've run it in all major browsers, so that any differences in the JS engine's implementation could be visible.

There's a few lessons here:

1. Sometimes the simplest solution is best
2. When you're processing a lot of data that you're not going to change, point to it if you can; don't spawn new objects to do the job a little math could handle.
3. Just because something is clever doesn't mean it's right (as a noob, you really need to take that to heart)
4. Note how the native implementation is almost as slow as the pointed recursive version, and in Chrome's case, slower.  I'm not exactly sure why this is, but I expect that it's implicit the cast from an Array to a native argument list, *twice* (via Function#apply()).  The performance hit we take for doing this is an unintended consequence, and is the sort of thing you need to look out for whenever using a library.  When you hit performance pain points in library code, it may just that the library code is trying to do more than you want it to; it may be that transitioning your data to the library's preferred format isn't performant. Whatever the problem is, sometimes hacking together an equivalent function without all the extras is the right answer.
5. Platform matters.  What's quick on one system might not be on another.  You don't have to test everything that's out there, but you should have an idea of what your users use, and test against each of those.

Answer (score 0):

Then there's the nested macro method (as mentioned by twalberg in the comments) i.e. let the compiler figure it out from simple constructs.  Modern compilers are good at that.

```
#define MIN(a,b) (a) < (b) ? (a) : (b)
```

The parens are important to get precedence and order of operations right.

To get a minimum of three numbers:

```
min3 = MIN(MIN(a,b), c);
```

Four numbers:

```
min4 = MIN(MIN(a,b), MIN(c,d));
```

And so-on.  This has the further advantage that you don't need different forms for integers or real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it

> 1. Put the elements in Array and find max/min.
> 2. Declare a max/min variable check the elements one by one and update ver according to the condition.

**For Example 1, I am writing Code, finding Max from an Array in C++**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[]{2,1,4,12,6,3,20};
    int sum = INT16_MIN;
    for(int x : arr){
        if(x>sum){
            sum =x;
        }
    }
    cout << sum;
    return 0;
}
```

**For Example 2, I am writing a function, finding Max from 4 elements in C++**

```
int max_of_four(int a,int b,int c,int d){
    int max = INT16_MIN; //Min Int(16) possible in Code
    if(a>max){
        max=a;
    }if(b>max){
        max=b;
    }if(c>max){
        max = c;
    }if(d>max){
        max =d;
    }
    return max;
}
```

you can replace "four" with N set of numbers, but this is not an efficient way. Use the 1st method for finding Max/Min

> For finding the Min Take the var as "INT16_MAX" and change the Condition
> from ">" to "<".